# Provisioned state failed when trying to add Shared Private Access on Search service

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search, azure-virtual-network, azure-private-link

I'm trying to allow my search indexer to connect to a cosmosdb behind a vnet. When adding a shared private access, the provisioning state is set to failed, without giving me an explanation. I have a private endpoint on the CosmosDB setup already. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue occur on the same day as you reported it.
I had been setting up running this connection via Azure Pipelines the day before but suddenly the same Pipeline stopped working.

I raised it as an issue with MS and it was quickly reproduced by the 1st line and passed onto escalation engineers who confirmed there was a recent change in the Fluent SDK used, when we initiate an ARM deployment for Shared Private Link resources we end up specifying both template link and template id (incorrectly/by accident). As a result, customers creating SPL resources are failing to do so with a 500.

I am told there is a world-wide fixed being rolled out and to be completed on Monday pacific time.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I just had this issue -> provisioning worked, then tried to re-run and am getting failures without a reason... the docs don't seem to specify how to determine the provisioning failure reason

Comment: Yes, it was fixed within the time frame they issued