# Azure Data Factory Private Endpoint provision fails without explanation

Tags: database, azure, pipeline, oracle-adf, endpoint

I am facing an issue when creating a private endpoint to Azure SQL Server in ADF. It always fails no matter what settings of the SQL server I choose. I tried creating the endpoint separately from the left-hand menu in ADF and also while creating a Linked Service.

The only information I get from Azure is "Provisioning state" status as "Failed" and the error message is simply "Failed to create PrivateEndpoint for client ". I followed steps from  various YouTube tutorials and also followed official Microsoft instructions. I think I did everything correctly. The creation seems pretty straightforward but the result is always the same.

I have tried with a different Azure account and it didn't work either. I've also tried creating the endpoints and all the resources in various regions (East US, West Europe). When I checked service health, there were no issues. As I have just the basic Microsoft Support plan, I could only raise a question to make sure, that this has nothing to do with my subscription. I can't raise any technical incident to MS.

Is anybody facing similar issues in the last days? I've been trying for 3 days already with no positive result. I think this might be some general service problem. Especially that a similar problem already occurred some time ago according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69989404/provisioned-state-failed-when-trying-to-add-shared-private-access-on-search-serv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself. This behavior has to do with subscription settings. If I understand correctly, it is not enabled by default for the private endpoints to be created. First the resource provider Microsoft.Network must be registered to your subscription. After you do that, you can create private endpoints with Azure Data Factory.